# What's the cheapest way to create an adhoc network

Tags: networking

I'm thinking about using my Raspberry Pi as a server for things like Scalatron or Startup Poker.

Therefore I'm wondering: What is the easiest/cheapest way to setup a network with

1 Raspberry Pi and about 2-6 other PCs with various OSs?

Can I just throw a hub on a table and everybody plugs in?

Comment: If you add a DHCP server to the Raspberry Pi, then connecting them with a hub would work. As a DHCP server is needed to give the other machines assigned IP addresses if you don't want to manual assign fixed IP addresses.

Comment: So I'd just setup a DHCP server on the Raspi and plug all computers in the normal ports of a hub? The uplink port stays empty? Does a hub even have an uplink thingy?

Comment: Neither hubs or switches have an uplink port, only routers do (N=5).

Comment: Thanks, wanna make that an answer so you can harvest your reputation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a DHCP server to the Raspberry Pi, then connecting them with a hub would work. As a DHCP server is needed to give the other machines assigned IP addresses if you don't want to manual assign fixed IP addresses.

Neither hubs or switches have an uplink port, only routers do (N=5).